# wrapper() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Tags: python, django-views

I have wiev-functions:

```
@login_required
def index(request):

@login_required
def detail(request, id):
```

decorator:

```
@decorator
def login_required(wiev_function, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
    return wiev_function(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

"index" function work correctly, but "detail" down with a error:

> TypeError: wrapper() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

P.S. id-parameter is in url-patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^new/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.new, name = 'new'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you write a decorator. A decorator is a function that *returns* another function; that inner function must then do some logic and (optionally) call the decorated function. The outer function itself does not take the parameters that are passed to the original function; the inner function does.

```
def login_required(view_function):
    def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
        return view_function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

However, all this seems pretty pointless as Django already provides a [`login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Answer (score 2):

I would solve it as this:

```
#decorator
def login_required(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not args[0]:
            return print('not valid')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@login_required
def index(request):
    print('1')

@login_required
def detail(request, id):
    print('2')

index(True)
index(False)
detail(True, 1)
detail(False, 1)
```

Comment: this's the answer